# Oracle directory - having difficulty reading a file that has group read disabled (oracle is in the group)

Tags: oracle, unix, directory

My Solaris user oscar is part or a group that contains the oracle user account.

I create a directory and place a file inside; make it owner and group readable

```
mkdir /tmp/tdir
echo $$ > /tmp/tdir/foo.txt
chmod 440 /tmp/tdir/foo.txt
```

I then log on as system and create an Oracle directory

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY tmp_tdir AS '/tmp/tdir';
```

I then start a sqlplus session (as system) from the database server, while logged on as unix user oscar.

I can read the file contents by executing this snippet in sqlplus

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  fileHandler UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  buffer    CLOB;
BEGIN
  fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('TMP_TDIR', 'foo.txt', 'r');
  UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(fileHandler, buffer);
  dbms_output.put_line('File Data: '||buffer);
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fileHandler);
END;
/
```

Now when I remove the group read permission from the file, the above snippet no longer works. Instead, I'm presented with the error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

Why am I unable to read the file once the group permission has been removed, given that the oracle sqlplus process is running as the file owner?

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the output of a command such as `ps` showing under which identity oracle is running? Could you show the output of `ls -ls` on your file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the OS authentication was not important in the context of this problem.

The issue was that utl_file won't allow file access if the *oracle* user does not have access.

The group associated with the file contains the *oracle* user. Therefore, I can only read the file with utl_file when the group read bit is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

OS users and Oracle users are two different things.

*OS authentication* will not imply that your oracle instance will run under the identity of the given user. Foe example, on my Linux system, Oracle XE is running as OS user *oracle*. This is the only identity that matters for granting or rejecting file access as OS level.

You could check that with a simple `ps`  command.

---

*Please note that if your OS/filesystem is using [ACL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1448/gbacb.html) or [Solaris Trusted Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_Trusted_Extensions) (Somewhat the equivalent of SELinux), things might be more complex than that though.*

Comment: My bad Sylvain, looking back at my original question, my explanation of the problem was unclear.